# Format a long string into a short string C#

Tags: c#, string

I have some strings such as:

1.5555555555555
2.3421354325435354545
4.509019292

I want to format them into a string such as:

1.5555
2.3421
4.5090

I tried to use the C# String.Format but I can not get it to correctly work.

Can someone please give me the correct c# statement to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you attempted? string.Format() with a number format string (such as g or f) depends on the input value being a number (decimal, float, double). So you would have to parse your number string first. If you just want to truncate without rounding, you could always just use string.Substring().

Comment: Do you have strings like 1003.1543234 as well? What should happen with those upon format?

Comment: these are not strings, they are decimals, your description is incorrect and missleading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unclear if you'll always be dealing with numeric values. If you want to avoid parsing the strings as numbers, you might try something like this:

```
public static string TrimTo(string str, int maxLength)
{
    if (str.Length <= maxLength)
    {
        return str;
    }
    return str.Substring(0, maxLength);
}
```

This will trim the provided string to six characters, if it's longer than six. This *seems* to be what you want, but (as Kees points out), will do something unexpected with a string like "1234567.890".

The conditional clause is necessary here because `String.Substring` will complain if the second index is outside of the string (if the string is shorter than `maxLength`, in other words).

(If you've played around with C# 3.0 [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) at all, you might recognize this, slightly modified from the above, as an excellent opportunity for one: `string trimmed = s.TrimTo(10);`)

Comment: I think this would be the best way to do it, considering that 1.555555555 rounds down to 1.5555.

Answer (score 3):

```
string.Format("{0:N4}",decimalValue);
```

[Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

[Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you convert the Strings to doubles you can use String.Format to specify how many decimal places you want to include when you reformat it as a String.

```
String.Format("{0:0.0000}", double.Parse("1.55555555555555"))
```